# Digitizing in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digitizing

What are the quickest and easiest ways of digitizing in ArcMap? I want to digitize pipelines on a pipe network map.

Comment: Have you tried using arcscan?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Typical general workflow for manual digitizing:

- scan the map(s)
- georeference the scanned maps
- create empty vector featureclass(es)
- start editing, drawing over the scanned maps

Comment: In addition to this when digitizing a pipe network there are lots of other things to consider.  Is this pipe gravity or pressurized.  Which way does it flow. Do you need a Z value for gravity modeling, etc... Also you really need to set up topology rules first for the network then digitize so you can ensure everything is connected properly so you wont have any problems creating a geometric network.

Answer (score 0):

[ArcScan](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm) -- An ArcMap extension (if you have the extension available). By adjusting the parameters as needed, this will allow you to bypass much manual digitizing.